# Qt QGraphicsScene items() segmentation fault

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene

I'm getting to know QGraphicsScene and whole QGraphics part of Qt. Now I'm trying to create a program which manages bezier curves (for modeling fuselage sections, that's why there are "sections" in code).

Implementing `QGraphicsScene` class:

```
class SectionScene : public QGraphicsScene
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit SectionScene(Database* database, QObject *parent = 0);
    BezierCurve* currentCurve();
signals:

public slots:
    void focusCurve(BezierCurve* curve);
    void addNode(BezierNode* node);
private:
    void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent* e);
    Database* database;
    BezierCurve* m_currentCurve;
    QPainter* painter;
};

SectionScene::SectionScene(Database* database, QObject *parent) :
    QGraphicsScene(parent)
{
    this->database = database;
    this->setSceneRect(-100,-100,200,200);
    connect(database,SIGNAL(curveFocus(BezierCurve*)),this,SLOT(focusCurve(BezierCurve*)));
    connect(database,SIGNAL(nodeAdd(BezierNode*)),this,SLOT(addNode(BezierNode*)));
    painter = new QPainter();
    addItem(new QGraphicsRectItem(QRectF(0,0,100,100)));
}

void SectionScene::addNode(BezierNode *node)
{
    addItem(node);
    if (node->leftControlPoint()) addItem(node->leftControlPoint());
    if (node->rightControlPoint()) addItem(node->rightControlPoint());
    update();
}

void SectionScene::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *e)
{
    if (e->button() == Qt::LeftButton && e->modifiers() == Qt::ControlModifier) {
        BezierNode* node = new BezierNode(e->scenePos());
        currentCurve()->appendNode(node);

    } else {
        if (items(e->scenePos()).size()) {
            QGraphicsScene::mousePressEvent(e);
        }
    }
}
```

And `BezierNode` class, which is `QGraphicsItem`:

```
class BezierNode : public QGraphicsItem
{
    Q_INTERFACES(QGraphicsItem)
public:
    enum Type {Symmetric, Smooth, Angular};
    BezierNode(QPointF point = QPointF(0,0), Type type = Symmetric);
    void setPoint(QPointF point);
    QPointF& point();
    void setLeftControlPoint(BezierControlPoint*);
    BezierControlPoint* leftControlPoint();
    void setRightControlPoint(BezierControlPoint*);
    BezierControlPoint* rightControlPoint();
    void setType(Type);
    Type type();

    QRectF boundingRect() const;
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget);
    QPainterPath shape() const;



public slots:
//  void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);
    //  void dragEnterEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event);
    bool sceneEvent(QEvent *event);
private:
    QPointF m_point;
    BezierControlPoint* m_leftControlPoint;
    BezierControlPoint* m_rightControlPoint;
    Type m_type;
    bool m_selected = false;
    bool m_hovered = false;
};

BezierNode::BezierNode(QPointF point, Type type) : QGraphicsItem()
{
    m_point = point;
    m_type = type;
    if (type == Symmetric) {
        BezierControlPoint* leftControlPoint = new BezierControlPoint(point - QPoint(30,0),this);
        BezierControlPoint* rightControlPoint = new BezierControlPoint(point + QPoint(30,0),this);
        setLeftControlPoint(leftControlPoint);
        setRightControlPoint(rightControlPoint);
    }
//  setFlags(ItemIsMovable);
}

QRectF BezierNode::boundingRect() const
{
    qreal size = 7;
    QPointF topLeft = m_point - QPointF(size,-size);
    QPointF bottomRight = m_point + QPointF(size, -size);
    return QRectF(topLeft,bottomRight);
}

void BezierNode::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
    painter->drawEllipse(boundingRect());
}

QPainterPath BezierNode::shape() const
{

    QPainterPath path;
    path.addEllipse(boundingRect());
}
```

On `mousePressEvent` in `SectionScene` behavior is following: With ctrl-modifier it properly creates `BezierNode` and draws it on view (there is only one view used, scene is binded to it). If there is left click without modifiers everything is alright if I click outside of `BezierNode` shape. But if I click on it, there comes segmentation fault at `items(e->scenePos())`. The same was with `itemAt(..)` and when I tried to just `QGraphicsScene::mousePressEvent(e)`. Can't get past it for many hours now, so I would like to hear your thoughts. Also, `sceneEvent(QGraphicsSceneEvent* event)` in `BezierNode` triggers on every scene event, even if it doesn't relate to this item. Is it how it should be?

Full compilable project can be found at [git](https://github.com/morodeer/bezierCurveExperiment.git) .

Comment: Does your debugger say that the owner of `items(..)` is null it's `e` argument?

Comment: @morodeer  you should probably turn on warnings in your compiler. There's a bunch of functions with return types that don't return anything liek `QPainterPath BezierNode::shape()`.

Comment: @PeterT, thank you! Lost it among other warnings, and had my head totally off. Adding return value to `shape()` helped.

Comment: @morodeer You seem to be ignoring a lot of warnings. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boundingRect and shape functions of a QGraphicsItem are responsible for checking if the position is colliding with the item when calling QGraphicsScene::items or itemAt.

You have stated this as the shape function: -

```
QPainterPath BezierNode::shape() const
{

    QPainterPath path;
    path.addEllipse(boundingRect());
}
```

So you're missing returning the shape that you've created.

While this may not be the cause the segmentation fault, it's still something which is going to cause you problems.

Comment: Thanks! It was really the problem with no return value specified, as you and @PeterT in comments noted. Should haved looked  at compiler's warnings.